# retrieving List<Entity> from List<Object[]> JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have an Entity class calle Publication, a method called getAllPublication that return `List<Publication>` , but my query inside the method has a resultList of type `List<Object[]>`, how can I retrieve a list of publication entity fromthe `List<Object[]>`:
-here the method :

```
public List<Publication> getAllPublication() {
    List<Object[]> listePublication;
    Query q;
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    q=em.createQuery("SELECT c.titrePublication,
    c.datePublication, c.corps,p.login FROM Publication c  JOIN c.employee p ");
    listePublication = q.getResultList();
    //ArrayList<Publication> results = new ArrayList<Publication>();
    //for (Object[] resultat : listePublication)
    //results.add((Publication) resultat[0]);*/
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return results;
}
```

thanks in advance.
here is the entity class

```
 package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Publication.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Publication p")
public class Publication  {


    @Id
    @Column(name="\"idPublication\"")
    private Integer idPublication;

    private String corps;

    @Column(name="\"datePublication\"")
    private String datePublication;

    @Column(name="\"titrePublication\"")
    private String titrePublication;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="auteur")
    private Employee employee;

    public Publication() {
    }

    public Integer getIdPublication() {
        return this.idPublication;
    }

    public void setIdPublication(Integer idPublication) {
        this.idPublication = idPublication;
    }

    public String getCorps() {
        return this.corps;
    }

    public void setCorps(String corps) {
        this.corps = corps;
    }

    public String getDatePublication() {
        return this.datePublication;
    }

    public void setDatePublication(String datePublication) {
        this.datePublication = datePublication;
    }

    public String getTitrePublication() {
        return this.titrePublication;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public void setTitrePublication(String titrePublication) {
        this.titrePublication = titrePublication;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you want a List<Publication>, the use a query that retrieves a list of publications: `select p from Publication p`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public List<Publication> getAllPublication() {
    TypedQuery<Publication> query = em. createNamedQuery(Publication.FIND_ALL, Publication.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

And your Entity looks like:

```
 package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name=Publication.FIND_ALL, query="SELECT p FROM Publication p")
public class Publication  {

    public static final String FIND_ALL = "Publication.findAll";

    @Id
    @Column(name="\"idPublication\"")
    private Integer idPublication;

    private String corps;

    @Column(name="\"datePublication\"")
    private String datePublication;

    @Column(name="\"titrePublication\"")
    private String titrePublication;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="auteur")
    private Employee employee;

    public Publication() {
    }

    public Integer getIdPublication() {
        return this.idPublication;
    }

    public void setIdPublication(Integer idPublication) {
        this.idPublication = idPublication;
    }

    public String getCorps() {
        return this.corps;
    }

    public void setCorps(String corps) {
        this.corps = corps;
    }

    public String getDatePublication() {
        return this.datePublication;
    }

    public void setDatePublication(String datePublication) {
        this.datePublication = datePublication;
    }

    public String getTitrePublication() {
        return this.titrePublication;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public void setTitrePublication(String titrePublication) {
        this.titrePublication = titrePublication;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a typed query by doing:

```
TypedQuery<Publication> q;
em.getTransaction().begin();
q=em.createQuery("SELECT c.titrePublication,
    c.datePublication, c.corps,p.login FROM Publication c  JOIN c.employee p ", 
    Publication.class);
```

Edit: as the other answers indicate, the query needs to be changed too to return all that is in the Publication table.

Answer (score 0):

JPA provides an `SqlResultSetMapping and resultClass` that allows you to map whatever returns from your native query into an Entity

You have to define Query `NamedNativeQuery` in your Publication.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="findPublication", query="SELECT c.titrePublication, c.datePublication, c.corps,p.login FROM Publication c  JOIN c.employee p", resultClass=Publication.class)
```

login property is not define in Publication class, you need add login peroperty in Publication with getter/setter because your selecting login from employee table using join